# On Target Board: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am using the imx6dlsabreauto board and linux kernel version 3.14.28, in host machine application run successfully but in  target machine when i run the application it throw an error "qrc:///Niam.qml:4 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed" and try all the possibilities of Internet solution but no luck, can any one help me what is wrong,

Comment: Your application is not properly deployed, it has to bundle all of its dependencies, libs, qml modules and so on.

Comment: other qml application is run properly,but when i run with below  import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
t throw an error, can you please suggest me what all the dependencies i need to add,

Comment: @NandishSg it depends which version of qt you are using to build the app

Comment: Hey Luka i am using" QMake version 3.0" and
" Using Qt version 5.2.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ",

Comment: @dtech: can you please tell me what are all the  dependencies ,libs i need to install.

Comment: @Luka: i chanegd the qmake version 3.0 to 3.1 and  qt version 5.2 to 5.9.1, but still the same issue, what is missing ,